# Change colour of calendar on ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, customization, calendar, google-calendar

I am using a google calendar with the calendar app on my ubuntu phone. Somehow by default the events and appointments are displayed in the app with a black colour. Is there a way to change this colour to something more appealing?

I am using the stable version of ubuntu-phone.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open a drop-down menu with the button in the right top corner.
2. Select 'Calendars'.
3. Do a long press on the black square that is next to the google calendar.
4. Color picker should appear.

For more precise control the colors of the color picker are defined in the source file
`/userdata/system-data/opt/click.ubuntu.com/com.ubuntu.calendar/current/ColorPickerDialog.qml` on the phone. So it's possible to manually smuggle some different color.

Comment: Thank you! It works and your answer is clearly written and understandable.

Comment: Doesn't work in "agenda" view (button isn't visible)